# Get records from two collection in mongoDB using limit and skip

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have two collection called "Order" and "Production Order ". I have record limit for 40 on each page  . So I need to display total 40 records from both .I have number of question as below mention .

1) Can we get records for two collection from one query ?.
2) If i will use two query its really hard to display because in case of "Orders " will come 30 and "Production Order  "will come 10 and if give limit of 20 for each collection 10 remaining will not display from "Orders "

Comment: (10 remaining will not display from "Orders " ) -- is it Order collection or Production Order collection?

Comment: is `Production Order` and `Order` are related to each other ?

Answer (score 0):

possible ways i can think now for your requirement will be

1) Use [relationShip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-relationships/) (`1To1`,`1ToMany`,`ManyToMany`) and then fetch relative data using `.populate()` function of [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) to get desired data

2) Or you can use data replication (inCase you done want relationship in Database)

```
"order": {
  "_id": "313424535435", // you can add other relevant data according to you need
  "production_order": {
    "_id": "127342684783" // only add that data which is necessary 
  }
}
```

and **Vice-versa**